# UIKeyboard will change frame with interactive keyboard dismiss, not called continuously

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikeyboard, nsnotifications

I am trying to use the `UITableView.keyboardDismissMode = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissMode.Interactive`, to be able to drag my keyboard up and down. However I can't find any way to track the keyboard frame to update my tableView frame and messaging view. I am simply trying to replicate the standard iMessage behaviour. Given the name, I would have thought that `UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification` would have been perfect for tracking the keyboard frame changes, but it only notifies when the gesture ends and the keyboard animates up or down.

Comment: FYI: http://www.openradar.me/14847817

Comment: any one find solution ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this will work but you could try to track the drag progress via the `panGesture` property on `UIScrollView` in your tableView. It wouldn't be a direct tracking of the keyboard frame, but if you know the keyboard's height and the progress/offset of the pan, you might be able to math your way around the problem.

Answer (score -3):

The best approach for interactive dismissal is to use the "UIKeyboardDidShowNotification" and "UIKeyboardWillHideNotification" system notifications. When the selector is called you update the table's bottom inset. NOT the constraints. Updating the inset will give you a beautiful smooth keyboard dismissal experience.

Comment: This doesn't update and follow the interaction of the keyboard.